# mysql select, sum, group by date when you have epoch or sysmillis for a time stamp

Tags: mysql

I have been wrestling around with various time/date manipulations in MySQL and have not figured out how to get this done. I am trying to select a daily sum of a column, `volume`. My date column contains sysmillis (epoch * 1000).  I have tried things such as

```
SELECT YEAR(from_unixtime(date/1000)) FROM...
```

and none of what I have tried does the trick. What I want to end up with is a result table that does a sum of all the transactions `volume` column, for each day. Seems like a pretty simple idea to me, but it just is not working. Is this something that I need to do a nested query to do or should this just be a simple one-liner, that I am just not getting the function right?

Comment: post some code for what you tried to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date/1000)) AS date, SUM(volume)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY date
```

should do the trick, unless your table structure is wonky.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(volume) FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTR( FROM_UNIXTIME(   ROUND(volumeDate /1000)   ), 1, 10) AS dayValue, 
        volume FROM `volumeTable`
    ) a 
GROUP BY dayValue
```

Comment: ummm...a string operation to extract a date from a datetime type? Why not just `DATE()`?